# onCallStateChanged() gives wrong CALL_STATE

Tags: android, telephonymanager

I have overridden the `onCallStateChanged()` method of PhoneStateListener to get the device call status, but I'm facing a weird issue on device Micromax turbo (OS- 4.2.1).

When an incoming call is received on this device, I get phone the state as ringing and after that I again receive a callback with the state as idle. I checked on another device (OS- 4.2.2) and it is working fine there. Is this a device or OS related issue?

Comment: in fact that many device manufacturers make their own version of android, for example samsung with TouchWiz, it is possible that they make faults....so, I think it is a device related problem. You should check other devices with the same version to get sure...

Answer (score 1):

When the phone starts ringing the phone state will be broadcasted as RINGING and after the phone is disconnected the state is broadcasted as IDLE. The state by the micromax seems correct.

If call is answered by the receiver

> CALL_STATE_RINGING->CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK->CALL_STATE_IDLE

If the call is not answered by the receiver,

> CALL_STATE_RINGING->CALL_STATE_IDLE

Comment: But the issue is, I am getting CALL_STATE_IDLE even if the phone is still ringing.